# Nagios Graph Data

Tags: nagios

I have recently setup nagios for monitoring our services and was successfully able to setup nagios graphs as well and it is working as expected.

I just have one question... while i move my mouse over graph it just shows the time, is there anyway we can get data as well? (i mean y-axis values).

In the attached screen shot we can see while moved mouse over i can see only timestamp but no data.

if some one has find the solution please let us know.

I am using Nagios core 4.3 and nagios graph plugin

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Which version of nagios? Which graphing add-on? That looks like pnp4nagios maybe? Which version?

Comment: Nagios core 4.3... i have installed nagiosgraph plugin (nagiosgraph-1.4.4.tar.gz)...

Comment: Can you add this information to your question, please?